# Find an entry in a multi-dimensional array where a part of a property matches with a given text

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array which contains three properties:

```
ID : number

Name : string

Description :string

ItemList :array<T>=[] and

ItemListCopy :array<T>=[]
```

Now it is bound to the `ng-multiselect` dropdown

Upon `onFilterChange` callback I am sending the search text to this callback method and trying to find all the items in `ItemListCopy` where `Name` contains the search text.

I tried the approach below:

```
var v = this.ItemListCopy.filter(item =>
    Object.keys(item).some(k => item[k].includes(text))
  )
  if (v != null && v.length > 0) {
    this.ItemList.length = 0;
    this.ItemList= v;
  }
```

Where text is the parameter that contains the search text.

But it gives the error `item[k].includes(text)` is not a method .

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have some data for testing and the wanted result?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with valid inputs and expected outputs

Comment: It probably should be: `this.ItemListCopy.filter(item => item.Name.includes(text))`

Comment: You should be checking specifically for matches in the `Name` property then, like @adiga said. Don't need to search through all the keys. Make sure `item[k]` is returning the object's `Name` value as you'd expect. Also if you're using IE, it doesn't support `includes()`.

Comment: @Jayce444  i am using chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just looking at the `Name`:

```
var v = this.ItemListCopy.filter(({ Name }) => Name.includes(text));
```

Comment: Is there any npm package for anngular or typescript where we can do c# linq like query from collections ?